# Toggle multiple Div names/content by one button click

Tags: html, button, click, toggle

i have 4 different divs in german. By clicking a button, i want to hide the german divs and instead show the english divs, which are hidden before.

There are ways to change between 2 divs, but how can i change mulitple divs at the same time by clicking one time on one button?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need JavaScript
or for an easier approach a JavaScript library like jQuery.

The basic approach is to add data-* attributes and classes to your elements:

```
<button class="langButton" data-language="en">EN ARTICLES</button>
<button class="langButton" data-language="de">DE ARTICLES</button>
<button class="langButton" data-language="it">IT ARTICLES</button>

<div class="article en">En 1...</div>
<div class="article en">En 2...</div>
<div class="article de">De 1...</div>
<div class="article de">De 2...</div>
<div class="article it">It 1...</div>
<div class="article it">It 2...</div>
```

than your jQuery might look like:

```
$(function() {   // Document is now ready to be manipulated

   // Cache all .article elements
   var $articles = $('.article');

   $(".langButton").click(function(){
       // Get the "en", "de" or "it" value
       var language = $(this).attr("data-language");
       // Hide all articles
       $articles.hide();
       // Show only the ones that have the ."language" related class
       $("."+ language ).show();
   });

});
```

Here's a [live jsBin example](http://jsbin.com/jamori/2/edit?html,js,output) you can play with or even download

Answer (score -1):

Are you restricted to not use a framework like jQuery?
jQuery offers multiple methods to run your code on more than one selected elements.

Here is a basic working solution in pure javascript for you:

```
var shown = 'english';

function swap() {
    if (shown === 'english') {
       document.getElementById('german-1').style.display = "inline-block";
       document.getElementById('german-2').style.display = "inline-block";
       document.getElementById('german-3').style.display = "inline-block";
       document.getElementById('english-1').style.display = "none";
       document.getElementById('english-2').style.display = "none";
       document.getElementById('english-3').style.display = "none";
       shown = 'german';
   } else {
       document.getElementById('english-1').style.display = "inline-block";
       document.getElementById('english-2').style.display = "inline-block";
       document.getElementById('english-3').style.display = "inline-block";
       document.getElementById('german-1').style.display = "none";
       document.getElementById('german-2').style.display = "none";
       document.getElementById('german-3').style.display = "none";
       shown = 'english';
   }
};
```

Link to jsfiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/v2k3rzge/

Hope it helps

Comment: this helps a lot! very nice and understandable function! thank you thousand times